ADF Snowflake Linked Service Update from Linked Service
I have a ADF that contains multiple legacy Snowflake linked service. Is there any way to bulk update it to the new Snowflake v2 rather than update it one by one (by creating new one multiple time)
One way that I found is that we can update the JSON file but it still need to be updated one by one

can you elaborate more what you have tried and error you are facing

It's not exactly an error so let me try to elaborate more. In my ADF, I have 3 linked service for Snowflake which has been legacy connector by now and I need to update it to the new one since my team decided to use Key Pair authentication (Which the old legacy Snowflake does not offer). So I want to know is there any way to update all 3 at once or I need to update the linked service one by one. I hope my explanation is clear and thank you for your help!

Please check the below answer and let me know if there is any issue

AFAIK we don't have any straightforward solution to update linked services in a bulk by automating it for that we need to use the REST Api's or Azure CLI command programmatically.

You can use the Update Linked Service API to update the configuration of the linked services programmatically.
Write a script that iterates over the list of linked services in your ADF and applies the new configuration for each one.

